# How to compare two openssl X509 certificate object C++

Tags: openssl, x509

I have two `X509` objects

```
X509 *cert1;
X509 *cert2;
```

How to I determine whether this two certificates are same or different? which property are identical for two same certificates?

Comment: See `int X509_cmp(const X509 *a, const X509 *b)` function

Comment: if the comparison yields equality, does it indicate that the certificates are same ?

Comment: There is two levels of comparison of X509 certificate:
1. X509 NAME comparison that compare issuer or subject (no extension,  expiration date and so).
2. Compare all data - our `X509_cmp` case. This function calculate a hash of full certificate and compare them by memcmp function. This function is the same as you can check hash from command line `#md5sum cert.crt`

Comment: Thanks for your information :) In my case, there are 2 certificates - one is coming from server and other is in my local directory. I want to verify the server certificate against my local certificate. Which type of comparison(1 or 2) can make sure - the certificate are identical or different?

Comment: For your case X509_cmp of course. X509_NAME using for certificate lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X509_cmp(const X509 *a, const X509 *b)` is perfect for byte by byte comparison of SHA_1 hash of two certificates. So @AlexBezuglyi is 100% correct. But actually I intended (but couldn't express in this question) to verify the server certificate whether its signed by the root certificate (trusted CA signed certificate).

### Using `X509_verify`

The signature of int `X509_verify` is

```
int X509_verify(X509 * x509, EVP_PKEY * pkey);
```

Suppose of you have root certificate in `root` and server certificate in `cert`

```
X509 * root;
X509 * cert;

//Get local certificate into root
//Get server certificate into cert

//Get the public key.
EVP_PKEY * pubkey = X509_get_pubkey(root);

//verify. result less than or 0 means not verified or some error.
int result = X509_verify(cert, pubkey);

//free the public key.
EVP_PKEY_free(pubkey);
```